# Permanently set environment variables for Multiple users

Tags: java, bash, shell, rhel, user-management

Java build machine is on Redhat 7.5 to run `mvn clean package deploy` for building Java code.

Multiple users login with their username to this build machine, to build Java code.

To permanently set `JAVA_HOME` & update `PATH` environment for all users,

Updating `/etc/profile` needs `sudo source /etc/profile` for every login, by every user. All users are part of `wheel` group

**Edit:**

Using `sudo` on internal command is invalid

---

How to permanently set these variables, for every login?

Comment: Are all your users using the bash shell or another shell? For bash, /etc/profile is usually read automatically and doesn't need to be sourced explicitly. Have you made sure that you exported the variables?

Comment: @RealSkeptic  It is bash. I did not export

Comment: Without export, those are not environment variables but shell variables. So you have to export. Emma's answer is the correct one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Editing /etc/profile should work, but not recommended.
you should create a new file in /etc/profile.d/ and set the JAVA_HOME there with export.

Answer (score 1):

There are some strange points in your question.

`sudo source /etc/profile` should normally give the answer `sudo: source: command not found`. `source` is not a command, but an internal. You can't `sudo` it.

Updating `/etc/profile` should work if the permissions on `/etc/profile` are correct, that is, at least r-- (644) for all users, although 755 is also common. In any case, do not restrict your `/etc/profile` to a specific group.

Comment: you are right... `source` is internal command like `cd`, `export`etc... My bad.